# Why Time is added with extra 5 hours when I send it to backend via POST API call?

Tags: c#, .net, angular, typescript, kendo-ui

I am passing an Object in a POST API call, where I am passing my desired Time. You can refer the screenshot below. Screenshot is captured after hitting the breakpoint which I have placed on selecting the date and time from the Kendo Date Time picker, where I do get correct time (i.e 12 AM ).

[image]

but when the date is passed to the backend (.Net is used for Backend), the time has added 5 hours.
[image]

this is for both Start Date and End Date.

I am using Angular(10) for Front End and .Net for Backend.

Below is the code where I collect the Date and Time from the Kendo Date Time picker

```
public endDateChange(value: Date): void {
    this.endDate = value;
  }
```

The above code is called when date is selected from a Kendo Date Time picker. And the same date is passed in the object which is passed to POST API call. You can refer the object below.

```
this.requestCheckout = {
  'Confirm Request': this.requestComments,
  'Profiles': this.checkoutProfiles,
  'ActingProvisionerId': this.idActingAs.ProfileUID,
  'isTimeBoundAccess' : this.isTimeBoundAccess,
  'StartDate': this.startDate,
  'EndDate': this.endDate
};
```

What wrong am I doing here that the Time is changed and selected time is not being passed to the backend.

Comment: If I had to guess, it's because it converts from the timezone (Eastern Time Zone, -5000) to GMT/UTC.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kendo DateTimePicker Not Handling UTC Offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35421255/kendo-datetimepicker-not-handling-utc-offset)